# For Loop/Average Price

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from collections import namedtuple
Car = namedtuple('Car','name year mpg price')

C1 = Car('Toyota', 1985, 21, 1000)
C2 = Car('Honda', 1994, 29, 2400)
C3 = Car('Kia', 2003, 26, 6000)

CL = [C1, C2, C3]
```

I need to create a function where I can find the average price of all the cars (given any list of tuples)

```
def sum_price(CL):
    for i in CL:
        print(sum(i.price))
```

^ I know this doesn't work for the sum... but I have no idea what to do

```
Sum/range(len(CL))
```

^ I know i should implement something like that to find the average

How do I approach this? Do I have to have my `sum_price(CL)` function print a list for the sum() operator to work?

Answer (score 5):

You're on the right track with `sum()`, but you should put the iteration inside it, so that it actually has something to add up:

```
def avg_price(CL):
    print(sum(i.price for i in CL) / len(CL))
```

To find the average, just divide by the length of the `list`. You don't need to divide it by all numbers from 0 to the length of the `list` (exclusive).

And I would use `return` here:

```
def avg_price(CL):
    return sum(i.price for i in CL) / len(CL)
```

Then put the call in a `print()` call:

```
print(avg_price(CL))
```

Comment: I think you should either rename the function to `avg_price` or keep the `/ len(CL)` out of the function.

Comment: That is very true, will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension inside the sum function call, ie

```
sum([i.price for i in CL])
```

this would be functionally equivalent

```
total = 0
for i in CL:
    total += i.price
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `list` - it can be just a generator.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.4 and above use the builtin [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) module and the [`mean` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean):

```
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> print(mean(car.price for car in CL))
3133.3333333333335
```